# Java: Constructor X in class X cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, constructor, package

I am creating a package mylib with classes Library{} and Book{}.

**Library class**:

```
package mylib;
import java.util.*;

class Library {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Book[] MyBooks = new Book[3];
    Book x;

    MyBooks[0] = new Book("The Lover's Dictionary", "Levithan, D.", 211, "AVAILABLE");
    MyBooks[1] = new Book("White Tiger", "Adiga, A.", 304, "AVAILABLE");
    MyBooks[2] = new Book("Thirteen R3asons Why", "Asher, J.", 336, "AVAILABLE");

    System.out.println("\n***** BOOK LISTING *****");
    for(int i = 0; i < MyBooks.length; i++) {
        x = MyBooks[i];
        System.out.println("[" + (i + 1) + "] " + x.sTitle + "\nAuthor: " +
            x.sAuthor + "\nPages: " + x.iPages + "\nStatus: " + Book.AVAILABLE);
        System.out.print("\r\n");
    }

    System.out.println("***** SELECT ACTION *****");
    System.out.println("B - Borrow a book");
    System.out.println("R - Reserve a book");
    System.out.println("I - Return a book");
    System.out.println("X - Exit program");

    System.out.print("\nEnter command: ");
    char cAction = input.nextLine().charAt(0); // Read single char

    switch(cAction) {
        case 'B':

            break;

        case 'R':

            break;

        case 'I':

            break;

        case 'X':
            Book book = new Book();
            book.exitProgram();
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("INVALID INPUT!");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

**Book class**:

```
package mylib;

class Book {
int iPages;
String sTitle, sAuthor;
String sBorrowedBy, sReservedBy;
String sDueDate, sReturnDate;
    String sStatus;

public static final String BORROWED = "BORROWED", AVAILABLE = "AVAILABLE", RESERVED = "RESERVED";

// Constructor
public Book(String title, String author, int pages, String status) {
    this.sTitle = title;
    this.sAuthor = author;
    this.iPages = pages;
    this.sStatus = status;
}
/*
void borrowBook() {

}

void reserveBook() {

}

 void returnBook() {

}
*/
 void exitProgram() {
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

In the `Library` class, I am trying to exit the program via switch, which calls the `exitProgram()` method from the `Book` class. I am receiving 1 error `constructor x in class x...`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the exit method static in Book.java

```
Book.java
static void exitProgram() {
  System.exit(0);
}

Library.java
 case 'X':
        //Book book = new Book();
        Book.exitProgram();
        break;
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3Hch0Qje - It compiles but still does not exit when I enter X?

Comment: Its working in my case ... Just try putting an SOP as follows :static void exitProgram() {
 System.out.println("Gonna exit");
    System.exit(0);
}

Comment: Is the cmd-prompt supposed to terminate Sir?

Comment: Yes ... The control should terminate

Comment: [This](http://imgur.com/4U9LaPR) is what happened so far. Is this the expected output? The cmd-prompt is still open Sir.

Comment: Yes .. The control is exiting .. This is the expected behaviour . It exited out of the java control .

Comment: Thank you, I thought the cmd-line box should also close.

Answer (score 0):

```
case 'X':
            Book book = new Book();
            book.exitProgram();
            break;
```

You don't have a constructor which can accept no-arguments

```
public Book() {
}
```

This should be defined in Book Class if you want to create "Book" without arguments.

OR

you should create Book object by passing required arguments

```
case 'X':
                Book book = new Book("test","test",1,"test");
                book.exitProgram();
                break;
```

Comment: I created the constructor that accepts no arguments. It compiles now. However, entering 'X' does not exit the program?

Comment: It will for sure. System.exit() will kill the Jvm. If JVM is not running, there's no way the program will be running.

Comment: I tested in my local, it's exiting. So just check what you are doing

Comment: Hi Reddy, here is what I did so far - http://pastebin.com/3Hch0Qje - where is it going wrong?

Comment: Your initial code with constructor change is working fine in my system. I tested now, it will work for sure. no reason, it won't work. which JDK are you using?

Comment: JDK 1.7.0_21. The cmd-line is supposed to terminate right? When I enter X, it only goes back to the dir of the package.

Comment: Hi Reddy, this is the [code](http://pastebin.com/c50phink). I am receiving this [output](http://imgur.com/4U9LaPR). Is that how it is supposed to be?

Comment: Thank you Reddy, the code actually works. I thought by "exit", the cmd-line prompt/box should close also.

Answer (score 0):

Java run time provides a default no argument constructor only when there is no constructor defined in a class. In your case you have a constructor with few arguments, hence the no argument constructor will not be added by the Java run time. You have to actually put a no argument constructor in your Book class.